# User set time for notification in swift

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, notifications, ios8

```
import UIKit
class MyView: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var mySwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet var myDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
    func datePicker() { myDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        datePicker()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func switchPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        if mySwitch.on{
            var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
            localNotification.alertAction = "Open App"
            localNotification.alertBody = "Here is your notification at 7:00 AM"
            localNotification.fireDate = myDatePicker.date
            localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
        } else {
            var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
            localNotification.alertAction = "Open App"
            localNotification.alertBody = "This notification should not appear"
            localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 999999999999)
            IApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What, exactly, is your question? If it's "how do I use a date picker", there are plenty of tutorial resources out there which will help with that.

Comment: No, sorry for not being clear, but I meant how do i connect my date picker to the fire date? I want the notification to appear every day at that time set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Combining Date and Time
//
//  Created by Leonardo Savio Dabus on 08/12/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 inDabusiness.com. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // IBOutlet goes here
    @IBOutlet var myDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet var mySwitch: UISwitch!

    // let = whatever goes here
    // var = whatever goes here
    var localNotification = UILocalNotification()   // You just need one
    var notificationsCounter = 0

    // put your functions now
    func datePicker()            { myDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date }
    func datePickerDefaultDate() { myDatePicker.date = NSDate().xDays(+1)              }
    func notificationsOptions()  {
        localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
        localNotification.repeatInterval = .CalendarUnitDay
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
        localNotification.alertAction = "Open App"
        localNotification.alertBody = "Here is the seven o'clock notification"
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
        //     you may add arbitrary key-value pairs to this dictionary.
        //     However, the keys and values must be valid property-list types
        //     if any are not, an exception is raised.
        // localNotification.userInfo = [NSObject : AnyObject]?
    }
    func toggleSwitch(){
        if mySwitch.on{
            localNotification.fireDate = myDatePicker.date.fireDate  // combined date = picked Date + 7:00am time
        } else {
            localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 999999999999)   // will never be fired
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        datePicker()
        datePickerDefaultDate()
        notificationsOptions()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    // here is where you place your IBActions

    @IBAction func switchPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        toggleSwitch()

    }
}
```

create a new Swift Source file at your project to put your extensions

```
import Foundation
public extension NSDate {
    func xDays(x:Int) -> NSDate {
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: x, toDate: self, options: nil)!
    }
    var day:            Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay,           fromDate: self).day           }
    var month:          Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth,         fromDate: self).month         }
    var year:           Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear,          fromDate: self).year          }
    var fireDate: NSDate    { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: year, month: month, day: day, hour: 7, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)! }
}
```

Comment: This is useful! However as I am getting an error from the public extension NSDate saying: declaration is only valid at file scope. @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Create a new empty swift file and paste it there

Comment: It is the public extension NSDate bit @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Look at the new edit for the question please @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Add a new file with it to your project.File > New File Source Swift

Comment: I know its tedious helping someone like me but its great people like you who make me and others better programers @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Right, now I have the new Swift file with your code, what do I do next? @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: How would you like me to send it? @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: You have to learn where to place your elements. You are mixing everything

Comment: Right. So I am trying to make it so the notification happens at 07:00 am every day but only if the switch is pressed on. I will send you the file if you tell me how to, thank you. @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Using your Finder, right-click you project folder and select "Compress yourProjectFolder". You can use dropbox.com

Comment: What is your dropbox name or email? @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: I'm just about to send it, the notifications come in every minute instead of every day now. Just hang on, almost done

Comment: Thats easy to fix. localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay

Comment: Have a look at the code I sent you @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Test it too! It seems to not be working right but with your programming skills I'm sure you can put it right! @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Yep, I checked it again @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Have you found whats wrong with the code? @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Yeah but I have a weird problem right now the switch it locked

Comment: Fixed deleting and adding another one

Comment: Funny the problem was the constraints I've added for the positioning

Comment: I didn't know constraints were that big an issue, but wow, I'm surprised! @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Do you want the default  date be always tomorrow?

Comment: Yes Please @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Will it appear every day from tomorrow until switch is turned off? @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Great! Can I look at it please? Also can I add to this later by making an afternoon one? @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: I have already finished the date part I will send you what I have done so far

Comment: Take a look. You can finish the notification part

Comment: I forgot to call the day + 1 to ajust the default date. let me fix 1 second

Comment: I just saw another problem the interval was set to second I changed to day

Comment: Okay, so now I will get a notification every day? @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Have you downloaded it?

Comment: Can I have the url? @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: When I was testing the last one it kept appearing every minute, I hope this doesn't happen. @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: You just have to use the CalendarUnitDay for the repeatInterval

Comment: Oh, okay, I will test this then, I will update on here if I have any troubles, thank you for your help!! Also, can I add new times in by re-using the code?

Comment: I think you also have to set the notifications timezone to local time zone

Comment: How do I do that? @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: The date specified in fireDate is interpreted according to the value of this property. If you specify nil (the default), the fire date is interpreted as an absolute GMT time, which is suitable for cases such as countdown timers. If you assign a valid NSTimeZone object to this property, the fire date is interpreted as a wall-clock time that is automatically adjusted when there are changes in time zones; an example suitable for this case is an an alarm clock.

Comment: What would I need to put in the code? And where will I need to put it? @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

Comment: Do I put this in togleSwitch function? @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Yes inside the function

Comment: Alright, in the future, can I contact you again and can you put in more switches that trigger at another time please but still linked to date from date picker please? @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: can you help me to make another notification appear when another switch is activated please?

Comment: just add another switch, connect the outlet at the top of the other, create another almost identical function named toggle2 or whatever and change only what needs to be changed or open another question that I will gladly help you

Comment: I think you should also suggest tomorrow date as fireDate only if localtime is already after 7am

Comment: Could you re-make the app again for me? I am finding it so hard to use these notifications but with other things, I am finding it easy. @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Look at the question again, I re-edited it with the code I have now. The thing is I don't actually know what to change. @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Look your question should be used by future visitors as a reference, if you change the question id doesn't make any sense anymore. You should revert your edit and copy your code into a new question, showing what you tried, the error you got and how you are supposed to fix it. This way I am helping also everybody else in the world, not only you.

Comment: Why did you create xDays2 ?

Comment: So I can have another time for the notification @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Sure there is already 60 comments here. open another question and revert you edits here.

Comment: Sorry @LeonardoSavioDabus , I changed it back, and here is the link to the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366127/setting-multiple-times-for-notifications-in-swift

Comment: My new question is here @LeonardoSavioDabus :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366127/setting-multiple-times-for-notifications-in-swift

Comment: I love stack overflow :)

Comment: @LeoDabus this ans is not compatible with swift 2.2, getting error **NSCalendarUnit has no member** kindly help if you can i am trying to create custom notification with given time and date.

Comment: @Arun I could post a Swift 4 version but using UserNotifications you wouldn't be able to set a fire date. It would schedule a daily notification starting at the next matching date or you can schedule a single future date notification (not daily).

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks a lot, Can you please update, I will update the code for daily notification

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the `UIDatePicker`, all you need to do is grab the `date` property from it and use it to set the `fireDate`.

Comment: So how would i actually do this? I can make the date picker display just the time. Now how do i put the time into the fireDate?

Comment: localNotification.fireDate = myDatePiker.date

Comment: I tried that @LeonardoSavioDabus i got an error for some reason, look at the comment below for what i have now and advise me on how to change it please, thank you.

Comment: What does every 24  once  mean?

Comment: I meant hour, will edit that now @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: What time is it happening every day? You need to fire it using any  date with a 7am hour and keep the repeating once a day

Comment: I would like that to be set by the date picker @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: So you can let the user select only a date and manually input 7am to that date

Comment: No no, I'm so sorry for my bad english, I want the notification to appear every day at 7 am @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Did you understand? You have to fire it at the desired date at 7am and repeat it every day as you already have done so far

Comment: OH! How do I do that? I'm sorry asking so many questions, but thank you for being so patient and helping @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: how do you set the date picker to pick only the Date or how do you create a Date Object using the selected date but with a specific time (7am) or both of them?

Comment: Both please @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: the second question let me see, just a minute

Comment: Done I posted how you have to create a custom fireDate