# Setting Multiple Times for Notifications in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, ios8

So I am using Swift now and I had one notification appearing at a certain time when one switch was activated.

However I would like another notification to come up at another time when another switch is activated.

Here is my code for ViewController:

```
 @IBOutlet var myDatePicker: UIDatePicker!

@IBOutlet var mySwitch: UISwitch!

@IBOutlet var mySwitchTwo: UISwitch!


var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
var localNotificationTwo:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()

func datePicker()            { myDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date }
func datePickerDefaultDate() { myDatePicker.date = NSDate().xDays(+1) }


func toggleSwitch(){
    if mySwitch.on{
        localNotification.alertAction = "Open App"
        localNotification.alertBody = "Please take your medication."
        localNotification.fireDate = myDatePicker.date.fireDate
        localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay
        localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
    } else {
        localNotification.alertAction = "Open App"
        localNotification.alertBody = "This notification should not appear"
        localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 999999999999)
    }
}

func toggleSwitchTwo() {
    if mySwitchTwo.on{
        localNotification.alertAction = "Open App"
        localNotification.alertBody = "Please take your medication."
        localNotification.fireDate = myDatePicker.date.fireDateTwo
        localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay
        localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotificationTwo)
    } else {
        localNotification.alertAction = "Open App"
        localNotification.alertBody = "This notification should not appear"
        localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 999999999999)
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func switchPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    toggleSwitch()
}

@IBAction func switchPressedTwo(sender: AnyObject) {
    toggleSwitchTwo()
}



}
```

Here is the first swift file with the time for first switch:

```
import Foundation
public extension NSDate {
func xDays(x:Int) -> NSDate {
    return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: x, toDate: self, options: nil)!
}
var day:            Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay,           fromDate: self).day           }
var month:          Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth,         fromDate: self).month         }
var year:           Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear,          fromDate: self).year          }
var fireDate: NSDate    { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: year, month: month, day: day, hour: 8, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)! }
 }
```

And I would like the next notification time at 1 PM. Here is the swift file I made for that:

```
 import Foundation
 public extension NSDate {
func xDaysTwo(x:Int) -> NSDate {
    return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: x, toDate: self, options: nil)!
}
var dayTwo:            Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay,           fromDate: self).day           }
var monthTwo:          Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth,         fromDate: self).month         }
var yearTwo:           Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear,          fromDate: self).year          }
var fireDateTwo: NSDate    { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: year, month: month, day: day, hour: 13, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)! }
 }
```

I am having problems with it and would really appreciate your help, thanks in advance!

Comment: What problems are you having? What is actually happening?

Comment: When I build it, it says build succeed but when I click the button that takes me onto the screen with my switch and date picker, I get a SIGABRT error @Dima

Comment: Are you using interface builder/storyboards? Did you actually hook up the IBOutlets/IBActions?

Comment: I hooked them up using the ctrl + drag thing. Before I had the second switch, it worked fine. I could connect the first switch with fireDateTwo and it would fire at that time. But now I have the second switch, I get that error. @Dima

Comment: You don't need two extensions for it

Comment: You only have to change the fireDate var to a function and pass the hour you would like to the set as a parameter.

Comment: Can I send the app I have made to you over drop box and can you fix it for me? It is for my GCSE Coursework @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Look at my answer and you will probably figure it out the rest just by yourself

Comment: I have also edit my answer to the other question and it is totally different from your actual code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27349421/2303865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet var mySwitch7am: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet var mySwitch8am: UISwitch!

    var localNotification7am = UILocalNotification()
    var localNotification8am = UILocalNotification()
    var notificationsCounter = 0

    func datePicker()            { myDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date }
    func datePickerDefaultDate() { myDatePicker.date = NSDate().hour > 8 ? NSDate().xDays(+1) : NSDate() }

    func notificationsOptions7am() {
        localNotification7am.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
        localNotification7am.repeatInterval = .CalendarUnitDay
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification7am)
        localNotification7am.alertAction = "Open App"
        localNotification7am.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    }
    func notificationsOptions8am() {
        localNotification7am.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
        localNotification7am.repeatInterval = .CalendarUnitDay
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification8am)
        localNotification7am.alertAction = "Open App"
        localNotification7am.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    }
    func toggleSwitch7am(){
        localNotification7am.alertBody = "Here is the seven o'clock notification"
        localNotification7am.fireDate = mySwitch7am.on ? myDatePicker.date.fireDateAt7am         : NSDate().xDays(+36500)
    }
    func toggleSwitch8am(){
        localNotification8am.alertBody = "Here is the eight o'clock notification"
        localNotification8am.fireDate = mySwitch8am.on ? myDatePicker.date.fireDateAt8am         : NSDate().xDays(+36500)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        datePicker()
        datePickerDefaultDate()
        notificationsOptions7am()
        notificationsOptions8am()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    @IBAction func switchedOn7am(sender: AnyObject) {
        toggleSwitch7am()
    }
    @IBAction func switchedOn8am(sender: AnyObject) {
        toggleSwitch8am()
    }
}
```

Extensions:

```
    import Foundation
    extension NSDate {
        func xDays(x:Int) -> NSDate {
            return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: x, toDate: self, options: nil)!
        }
        var day:            Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay,           fromDate: self).day           }
        var month:          Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth,         fromDate: self).month         }
        var year:           Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear,          fromDate: self).year          }
        var fireDateAt7am: NSDate    { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: year, month: month, day: day, hour: 7, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)! }
        var fireDateAt8am: NSDate    { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: year, month: month, day: day, hour: 8, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)! }
        func fireDateAt(hr:Int, min:Int) -> NSDate {
            return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: year, month: month, day: day, hour: hr, minute: min, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!
        }
    }
```

Comment: OH! Then i just connect the next switch in and change fire date to fireDateAt8am?