# Swift NSCalendarUnit setValue forComponent not working

Tags: swift, ios7, ios8, nscalendar

I am trying to create some date objects.

```
var gregorian:NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!;

var unit : NSCalendarUnit = (NSCalendarUnit.YearCalendarUnit|NSCalendarUnit.MonthCalendarUnit|NSCalendarUnit.DayCalendarUnit|NSCalendarUnit.HourCalendarUnit|NSCalendarUnit.MinuteCalendarUnit);
var interval:Double = Double(i)*60*60*24;
var tomorrow:NSDate = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(interval);

var comps:NSDateComponents = gregorian.components(unit, fromDate: tomorrow);

comps.setValue(17, forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.HourCalendarUnit);
var five_tomorrow : NSDate = gregorian.dateFromComponents(comps)!;

comps.setValue(19, forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.HourCalendarUnit);
var seven_tomorrow : NSDate = gregorian.dateFromComponents(comps)!;

comps.setValue(21, forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.HourCalendarUnit);
var nine_tomorrow : NSDate = gregorian.dateFromComponents(comps)!;
```

This seems to work fine on my iOS8 phone. But on my iOS7 device I print the dates and get `2015-03-03 19:33:00 MST` for all of the them. Any guesses as to why this is happening?

**Edit:**
What I am trying to do is get the date for around 5:00, 7:00, 9:00, and 10:00 pm tomorrow to set a local notification. I don't care so much about the minutes.

Comment: I am trying to set up a fireDate. 7pm is what I am shooting for but 7am will work too I guess.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27367185/2303865

Comment: I shouldn't answer it twice just upvote if it solves your problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting Multiple Times for Notifications in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366127/setting-multiple-times-for-notifications-in-swift)

Comment: The NSCalendar.currentCalendar() method is throwing an error for me. [_NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper dateWithEra:year:month:day:hour:minute:second:nanosecond:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1782273c0

Comment: You need all extensions

Comment: All read only computed properties that are included with the method fireDate

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2qwq184xsgrcxkg/TestingNotificationsAtSevenAM.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

It's used only on ios 8.0 and later.

```
@availability(iOS, introduced=8.0)
func setValue(value: Int, forComponent unit: NSCalendarUnit)
```