# swift not updating textfield.text using UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uidatepicker

In swift, I have a textField programmatically declared.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
textField3.delegate = self

    textField3.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Next;
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleDatePicker:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    textField3.inputView = datePicker


}

 func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {

    textField3.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
            }
```

All the other questions I've found similar to this deal with interface builder, and haven't helped. How would i fix this programmatically?

Comment: Have you tried creating a DatePicker and TextField separately, setting the TextField's inputView to the DatePicker, setting the DatePicker's delegate to self, and updating the TextField text in the didSelectRow method?

Comment: i'm sorry, i didn't quite understand what you meant. I wasn't aware DatePickers had delegates, and i'm not sure of any didSelectRow method available for uitextfields

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27367185/2303865

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus I noticed that there is an IBAction in the DatePicker that is called when editing Changed. How would I call a similar function without ibaction. Thanks

Comment: Whats wrong with IBAction? Just call your method from the IBAction

Comment: I don't have a storyboard/xib file. This is all programmatic, therefore I don't know how to link an ibaction to a programmatically declared datepicker @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: @YichenBman When you create it programmatically you don't need an outlet. The selector method doesn't have to be connected to an IBAction. Try to do as I suggested in my answer and let me know if you need further help. It should be pretty simple.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Xcode 9 • Swift 4**

```
@objc func handleDatePicker(_ datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
    textField3.text = datePicker.date.formatted
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDatePicker), forControlEvents: .valueChanged)
}
```

---

```
extension Date {
    static let formatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
        return formatter
    }()
    var formatted: String {
        return Date.formatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: currently I have everything set up the way you put it, however I changed the function so that rather than change `textField3.text` I just `println("hello")`. No print to the logs, and its not getting called when I place breakpoints on it. I changed `UIControlEvents.ValueChanged` to `UIControlEvents.AllEvents` but it still doesn't print anything to the logs and breakpoints show that this function is still not being called. It doesn't have any parameters, and I've removed the `:` so that the selector doesn't think I'm calling a function with parameters. thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3** version of @Leo Dabus answer:

```
func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        textField3.text = datePicker.date.formatted
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDatePicker(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
}

extension Date {
    var formatted: String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
        return  formatter.string(from: self as Date)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In, Swift 4
confirm to **UITableViewDelegate**
make txtFChequeDate.delegate = self

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    let datePickerView = UIDatePicker()
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = .date
    txtFChequeDate.inputView = datePickerView
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDatePicker(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

    if txtFChequeDate.text == "" {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
        txtFChequeDate.text = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    }
}

@objc func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
    txtFChequeDate.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
}
```